# Python statsmodels add_constant version issue

Tags: python, statsmodels

I want ask, in which version of `statsmodels` was `has_constant` function added for OLS? I work on `debian wheezy`, where is only `0.4.2` supported. On localhost I have `0.6.1` version and `has_constant` is supported and it works fine.

code is:

```
mat_zavisle_L = sm.add_constant(mat_zavisle_L, prepend=True, has_constant='add')
results = sm.OLS(endog=mat_cena_L, exog=mat_zavisle_L).fit()
```

and it gives me error:

```
add_constant() got an unexpected keyword argument 'has_constant'
```

So based on this, my conclusion is that `statsmodels 0.4.2` did not support `has_constant` for OLS. I was looking on documentation and relase history of statsmodels, but did not find something relevant. So is there some another function, which do same things as `has_constant` for `0.4.2 version`?

Answer (score 1):

You mean `has_constant` keyword argument in function `add_constant()` I guess.

Unless [the docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/generated/statsmodels.tools.tools.add_constant.html) are wrong, it was introduced after 0.6.0.

For a function that does the same, if you want it to be as powerful as `add_constamt()` look at the source code of the last version. Or patch the old version so it not check for constant columns. Or you can implement a simpler version that works with your data. For example for 2D arrays:

```
def add_constant(data):
    cons = np.ones(data.shape[0])
    return np.c_[cons, data]

add_constant(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]]))

array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  4.,  9.]])
```